# how to avoid thread divergence in this CUDA kernel?

Tags: cuda

for the CUDA kernel function, get branching divergence shown below, how to optimize it?

```
int gx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
val = g_data[gx];

if (gx % 4 == 0)
    val = op1(val);
else if (gx % 4 == 1)
    val = op2(val);
else if (gx % 4 == 2)
    val = op3(val);
else if (gx % 4 == 3)
    val = op4(val);

g_data[gx] = val;
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution by changing the work per thread

The best solution with the existing data layout is to let every thread compute 4 consecutive values. It's better to have fewer threads that can work properly than have more that can't.

```
float* g_data;
int gx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
g_data[4 * gx] = op1(g_data[4 * gx]);
g_data[4 * gx + 1] = op2(g_data[4 * gx + 1]);
g_data[4 * gx + 2] = op3(g_data[4 * gx + 2]);
g_data[4 * gx + 3] = op4(g_data[4 * gx + 3]);
```

If the size of g_data is not a multiple of 4, put an if around the index operations. If it is always a multiple of 4 and properly aligned, load and store 4 values as a `float4` for better performance.

### Solution by reordering the work

As all my talk about float4 may have suggested, your input data appears to be some form of 2D structure where one every four elements share a similar function. Maybe it is an array of structs or an array of vectors -- in other words, a matrix.

For the purpose of explaining what I mean, I consider it a Nx4 matrix. If you transpose this into a 4xN matrix and apply a kernel to this, most of your problems disappear. Because then entries for which the same operation has to be done are placed next to each other in memory and that makes writing an efficient kernel easier. Something like this:

```
float* g_data;
int rows_in_g;
int gx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
int gy = threadIdx.y;
float& own_g = g_data[gx + rows_in_g * gy];
switch(gy) {
case 0: own_g = op1(own_g); break;
case 1: own_g = op2(own_g); break;
case 2: own_g = op3(own_g); break;
case 3: own_g = op4(own_g); break;
default: break;
}
```

Start this as a 2D kernel with blocksize x=32, y=4 and gridsize x=N/32, y=1.

Now your kernel is still divergent, but all threads within a warp will execute the same case and access consecutive floats in memory. That's the best you can achieve. Of course this all depends on whether you can change the data layout.

Comment: This is the way to go if you can do the `float4` load/store. (When I wrote my answer, the type of `val` was not specified.  It's less interesting if `val` is a `double`, or 64 bit int, for example.)  If not, I'm concerned that by breaking coalescing you will end up with lower performance than the original code.  This is partly a problem with the question itself.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I agree that this is a downside. However, the compiler can reorder all load operations to happen in parallel. Then they all hit the L2 cache at the same time. This shouldn't be too bad, especially if the operations themselves are not cheap. Some benchmarking would be in order, though. Of course the best way would be to transpose the input array

Comment: Hello Homer512, can you elaborate more about "transpose the input array"? How the transpose help dealing with the warp divergence?

Comment: @Ericlass I hope I've made it clear in my edit

Answer (score 1):

If I were programming in CUDA, I certainly wouldn't do any of this.  However to answer your question:

> how to avoid thread divergence in this CUDA kernel?

You could do something like this:

```
int gx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
val = g_data[gx];

int gx_bit_0 =  gx & 1;
int gx_bit_1 = (gx & 2) >> 1;
val = (1-gx_bit_1)*(1-gx_bit_0)*op1(val) + (1-gx_bit_1)*(gx_bit_0)*op2(val) + (gx_bit_1)*(1-gx_bit_0)*op3(val) + (gx_bit_1)*(gx_bit_0)*op4(val);

g_data[gx] = val;
```

Here is a full test case:

```
$ cat t1914.cu
#include <iostream>

__device__ float op1(float val) { return  val + 1.0f;}
__device__ float op2(float val) { return  val + 2.0f;}
__device__ float op3(float val) { return  val + 3.0f;}
__device__ float op4(float val) { return  val + 4.0f;}

__global__ void k(float *g_data){

  int gx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
  float val = g_data[gx];

  int gx_bit_0 =  gx & 1;
  int gx_bit_1 = (gx & 2) >> 1;
  val = (1-gx_bit_1)*(1-gx_bit_0)*op1(val) + (1-gx_bit_1)*(gx_bit_0)*op2(val) + (gx_bit_1)*(1-gx_bit_0)*op3(val) + (gx_bit_1)*(gx_bit_0)*op4(val);

  g_data[gx] = val;
}

const int N = 32;
int main(){

  float *data;
  cudaMallocManaged(&data, N*sizeof(float));
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) data[i] = 1.0f;
  k<<<1,N>>>(data);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t1914 t1914.cu
$ compute-sanitizer ./t1914
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
5
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Hey Robert, "val" type is float, and the return from op(val) is also float. When I implemented as you suggested, I got some errors like "1.#QNANO". May it relate to type mismatch between val and gx_bit_0 and gx_bit_1. Any thoughts?

Comment: `int` times `float` is a `float`.  I don't see any issues as far as typing goes.  I created a full test case, and it seems to work fine according to my simple test case.

Comment: It works now. But the kernel runtime actually goes up instead of going down. Maybe the operation cost is so high. When you combine them together for each thread, it blurs the benefits by removing the divergence?

Comment: As I indicated in the very first line, I would not do this.  I'm not surprised the kernel runtime went up.  Try the suggestion in the other answer, especially if you can do `float4` vector load/stores.

Comment: As the operations are not SIMD-able, I don't see how this can be better than what OP does. You still need to execute all four operations per thread, right? I can see how this can be useful for half2 though.